# System.ArgumentException: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to follow the instruction from this page (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-search) on how to create a search page with a dropdown list for a site. But can't seem to get the dropdown list. It keeps giving me this error:

> System.ArgumentException: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. Parameter name: key

The problem is: CountryList.AddRange(CountryQry.Distinct());

SEARCH CONTROLLER :::

```
    public ActionResult Index(string location, string searchString)
    {

        var CountryList = new List<Country>();

        var CountryQry = from d in db.Stuffs
                         orderby d.Country
                         select d.Country; 

        CountryList.AddRange(CountryQry.Distinct());
        ViewBag.location = new SelectList(CountryList);

        var stuff = from m in db.Stuffs
                     select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            stuff = stuff.Where(s => s.stuffName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
        {
            stuff = stuff.Where(x => x.Country.countryName == location);
        }


        return View(stuff); 
    }
```

VIEW :::

```
    <form>
         @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Search",FormMethod.Get)){ 
              @Html.TextBox("SearchString", new { placeholder = "text" }) 
              @Html.DropDownList("location", "All")      
         }
    </form>
```

Model ::: (this was auto-generated from the database)

```
public partial class Stuff
{
    public string stuffId { get; set; }
    public string stuffName { get; set; }
    public string countryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

My c# knowledge is very limited, thus, I'm hoping someone can help me with this.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that the `Distinct` method expects a criterion for comparing `Country` objects. Your `Country` class is a complex class, which probably has several properties and does not implement the `IComparer` interface. This interface declares a method for comparing two objects and it is used by the `Distinct` method to find out if two objects are "equal".

You should implement the `IComparer`/`IComparable` interfaces in the `Country` class.

Assuming your `Country` class has a similar structure (regarding properties) you can do something like this (two countries are compared based on their name, but you can easily change the comparison property):

```
public class Country : IComparer
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Capital { get; set; }
     public int Population { get; set; }

     int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
     {
        Country c1=(Country )a;
        Country c2=(Country )b;

        if (c1.Name < c2.Name )
           return 1;

        if (c1.Name > c2.Name )
           return -1;

        else
           return 0;
     }
}
```

**EDIT**: The `IEqualityComparer` interface might be required instead of `IComparer`.

Another **EDIT**: One way around all this is to use:

```
var uniqueCountries = CountryQry.GroupBy(c => c.Name).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Using the "CountryQry" didn't work. But if I substitute it with "db.Countries", it works...it just doesn't bind the "Stuff" and "Country." At lease it doesn't give me an error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This answer does not work when it comes to Linq to Entity. IComparer and IEqualityComparer implemented return the same error. You need to specify the underlying property of the object.